# Ubuntu - I can't lauch apps and run command with sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

I am writing this post because after several hours of research I did not manage to find an answer.

I have been using Ubuntu 20.04 for a few months in dualboot on my original Windows. But since a few days I have not been able to launch applications (example: Chromium, Firefox, Visual Studio Code, Settings), I tried to launch them via the terminal, but I have no response, not even an error. I also cannot execute a command with sudo

After several searches I understood that it could come from gnome, I then try several subject recommend it to execute

```
$ killall gnome-control-center
$ gnome-control-center
```

When I try to kill I get no response, and when I run `gnome-control-center` I get the following error :`Failed to register: Timeout was reached`

I cannot move forward in my plans because of this problem, would you have a solution please?

Answer (score 0):

This might just be that something on your system is corrupted, you might just  have to copy the files you use all the time (Code, pdfs) wipe the drive and reinstall your ubuntu. Also, check if the Windows is working if that's not working it might be a problem with your computers internals.

Comment: I've had to restart a few times because my system got corrupted on my Raspberry Pi because of power outages.

Comment: My Windows is working properly, and I have already rebooted more than 10 times.. Is reinstalling everything the only solution?

Comment: I'm not sure look around for solutions, but it might be. It's possible it's just the linux so try wiping only the linux if you can so you can save your windows. :(